# How to set different background colors to items in listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

All I could see was by using 'custom adapter' and 'getview' method only.

I am populating a list view from database using arrayadapter. Can't we set different background colors to items in listview using an arrayadapter?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter is not a structure suitable to show a database table. Use [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) instead.

In getView you can set then any color for the row or a cell.